# Find correlation of x and y, given E(Y|X) and E(X|Y)

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation

Suppose that X and Y are random variables such that E(Y | X) = 7 - (1/4)x and E(X | Y) = 10 - Y . Determine the correlation of X and Y .

Edit:

So far I've got

E(x)=4 
E(y)=6

Now I'm trying to find

E(xy) to use in cov(x,y)=E(xy)-E(x)E(y)

V(x)

V(y)

all to use in cor(x,y)=cov(x,y)/(v(x)v(y))^.5

Comment: Correlation as measured by...?

Comment: cor(x,y) = cov(x,y) / (v(x)v(y))^.5  ...Im not sure I understand your question though

Comment: Pearson's is a fine way to define correlation; it's just not the only way.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $E[Y\mid X]$ is the *minimum-mean-square-error estimator* of $Y$ given the value of
$X$.  The **linear**  *minimum-mean-square-error estimator* of $Y$ given the value
of $X$ is

$$\hat{Y} = \mu_Y + \frac{\rho\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}(X-\mu_X).$$

Similar statements apply to $E[X\mid Y]$ etc. Just interchange $X$ and $Y$ in the
above formulas.

Now, if $E[Y\mid X]$ is a linear function of $X$ and $E[X\mid Y]$ is a linear
function of $Y$, can you use the *known* forms of the linear minimum-mean-square-error
estimators to deduce the value of $\rho$?

Comment: yeah Ive found E(y)=6.  Any other hints?

Comment: You don't need to find $E[Y]$ or $E[X]$. Hint: show that the coefficients of $X$ and $Y$ in the equations _given_ to you are $\rho\sigma_Y/\sigma_X$ and $\rho\sigma_X/\sigma_Y$ and use the information _given_ to you to deduce that $\rho=0.5$ **without** needing to find $E[X]$ or $E[Y]$ or $\text{var}(X)$ or $\text{var}(Y)$ or $\text{cov}(X,Y)$ or $E[XY]$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate (+1), but I think you meant to write $\rho = -1/2$ in your comment.

Comment: @r.e.s. Yes, you are correct. I realized that I had neglected to take the sign of $\rho$ into account after it was too late to edit the comment and was going to write a further comment. Thanks for the upvote.